# Connect a UDP socket, but still receive datagrams from other sources

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, udp

Is it possible to set the default destination of a UDP socket just like [`connect`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) does, but without loosing the ability to receive datagrams from other sources?

I'm talking about the native OS socket API (BSD-socket / winsock2) and I'm interested in answers for both linux and windows platforms.

[**EDIT**:]
In case this is unclear, here is the problematic part from the [connect docs](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect):

> If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received.

Comment: Can't you just use [sendto](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) with required destination address instead of calling `connect`?

Comment: @dewaffled: Sure I can, but that means that I have to keep around the destination address struct and to the best of my knowledge it is also less efficient (although that is probable not noticeable in most scenarios).

Comment: also note that network errors (e.g. ICMP destination unreachable) will be forwarded to `connect`ed UDP sockets. this may or may not be useful to you, but it's not normally something a server can do anything about as there are many cases where these won't be sent back

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to set the default destination of a UDP socket just
>   like connect does, but without loosing the ability to receive packages from other sources?

As far as I can tell, it is not -- `connect()` on a UDP socket both sets a default-send-destination *and* installs a filter so that incoming UDP packets from all other destinations than the specified address/port are dropped.

My solution to the problem was to just call `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` instead (if you have a `UDPSocket` class or similar in your codebase, you can cache the default-send address as a private member variable in that class, so that the rest of your codebase can just call a `Send()` method, and leave it to that method to handle the `sendto()` arguments)